# passing whole strings as arguments in fish shell

Tags: parameters, parameter-passing, fish

I have a number of cases where I need to pass free-form (i.e. containing white space and symbols as well as alphabetical symbols) strings as parameters to a function in fish shell.

Here's an example where I try to use getopts (to no avail):

```
function create_a_note --description 'create a new text note'
    
  set -l title ''
  set -l tags ''

  getopts $argv | while read -l key value
      switch $key
          case t title
              set title $value
          case g tags
              set tags $value
      end
  end

  if test -z $title
    error "title must be set (use the -t option)" >&2
    return 1
  end

  # do something interesting with the title and tags
end
```

I invoke it like this:

```
create_a_note -t 'my very interesting note' -g '@blah @rhubarb'
```

Whenever I use this kind of approach, the  variables `$title` and `$tags` get the first word of the strings (i.e. `$title == 'my'` and `$tags == '@blah'`) rather than the whole string.  I get why this is happening, where the string is converted to a list and the first element of the list is returned.

My question is - is there a way around this within fish shell?  I don't want to just pass in `$argv` and parse it myself unless there is no other option.

Use of `getopts` is optional, if you'll pardon the pun.

Comment: using `fish, version 3.0.2` on NixOS

Comment: You might investigate the [`argparse`](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/argparse.html) command instead of using getopts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My suggestion is to stop using `getopts`, an interface which I can never get right, and instead use fish's built-in argument parsing tool, `argparse`.

```
function create_a_note --description 'create a new text note'
    
  set -l title ''
  set -l tags ''
  argparse 't/=+' 'g/=+' -- $argv
                       
  if test -z "$_flag_t"
    echo "title must be set (use the -t option)" >&2
    return 1               
  end                      
                           
  echo $_flag_t; echo $_flag_g
end
```

In particular, `argparse 't/=+' 'g/=+'` means "a `-t` option which requires an argument, and a `-g` option which requires an argument". These arguments are stored in `$_flag_t` and `$_flag_g` respectively. There's more information in the [argparse manual](https://fishshell.com/docs/current/cmds/argparse.html).

Comment: It didn't work either, which got me digging deeper.  I am actually invoking this function through a kind of indirection mechanism that culminates in a call like this: `eval "$$fun $params"`.  

I think the issue is that string interpolation/embedding removes the quote symbols.  When I invoke the function directly, then your solution works fine (I wouldn't be surprised if getopts works OK too!).  Marking your answer as the solution.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think you would need to use double quotes: `$example == "example text w/ spaces and quotes"`. Or you might need to escape the spaces: `$example == 'example\ text\ w/\ spaces\ and\ backslashes'`. Also, if Wikipedia is anything to go by, every variable is an array so you might need get the array content instead of the first value in the array, which is what I think is happening.

EDIT: I didn't read the question correctly. In any case the solution would be almost the same:

- Quotes: `create_a_note -t "my very interesting note" -g "@blah @rhubarb"`
- Escape" `create_a_note -t my\ very\ interesting\ note -g @blah\ @rhubarb`

Comment: I tried various forms of quoting - doesn't work.  As for escaping everything - that is not user friendly enough to be worthwhile.  I'm pushing the title string through a series of regexes to convert it into a file system friendly slug.  With that approach, I might as well do it by hand,

Comment: I'm on macos where for some reason spaces are escaped instead of using quotes like everyone else does so that's where I got the escaping approach from. Honestly, I don't know if escaping the spaces would work on linux because I've never seen spaces escaped anywhere other than macos.